# how to push data to array with while loop PHP

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I want to crawl a few pages with `preg_match_all()` and save the data to one array(`$matches`), the url looks like :
`webpage.com/p/1` and the nuber at the end is the number of subpage and has to change with each run.
I thought about something like that(there are 10 subpages):

```
$x = 1;
while ($x <= 10) {

    $current_page = 'webpage.com/p/$x';
    $subpage = file_get_contents($current_page);    
    preg_match_all('regexp', $subpage, $matches);
    $matches = $matches[1];


$x++;
}
```

but seems like the array contain only the data from 1st run, what do I do wrong?

Comment: `$matches = $matches[1]` You know what this code does?

Comment: Check array_push () https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_push.asp

Comment: $matches is a string. You need to use `$allmatches[] = $matches[1];` I mean matches in the last line. Really confusing to use the same name on two things. As you can see that is a bad thing

Comment: when I do like @Andreas suggest i get 6 arrays with same elements, the ones matched from the 1st page

Comment: Are you using regex on HTML?

Comment: Give us some examples then. We don't even see your pattern.

Comment: yeah, i know it's not a perfect tool, but i'm just grabbing links from each page, and i get exactly the matches I want

Comment: @Andreas after fixing the url variable and using `$allmatches[] = $matches[1]` I end up with 5 sub arrays, how do I flaten the `$allmatches` array to have all results as elements in 1 flat array?

Comment: I don't like being kept in the dark either you show us what you have or you fix it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$current_page = 'webpage.com/p/'.$x;
```

$x previously is a static string and didn't change in loop.

Comment: You can also replace the ' with " and his code would be fine. https://3v4l.org/uvMhe

Comment: @sh00t no that is not all you are missing. You are using regex on HTML and that will come back and bite you. It's not much more work to do it properly. And you were overwriting your string with the match from the regex.

Comment: unfortunatelly that's project's requirement, i have to do it with regex, btw I saw the post about parsing html with regex and know it's no good, just have to..

Comment: @sh00t Requirement? By who? Your customer? If you don't like dom you can use substr(), strpos() and strip_tags(). I'm quite sure that will work at least.

Comment: teacher not customer, I guess that my skill level needs much improvements if I want to have customers ;) anyway I made it work, and thanks for the tip about substr and strpos, i'll look into it :)

Comment: @sh00t your teacher is requiring regex on HTML. You should tell him/her to come here and have a little chat.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something akin to the following - making sure you don't overwrite `$matches` as was happening

```
$data=array();
$regex='';
for( $i=0; $i < 10; $i++ ){
    $html = file_get_contents( 'http://www.webpage.com/p/'.$i );    
    preg_match_all( $regex, $html, $matches );
    $data[] = count( $matches ) > 1 ? $matches[1] : false;
)
$data=array_filter($data);
print_r( $data );
```